# How to log key presses/keyboard events for a short period of time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

I'm coding up a psychology experiment in Javascript and need to record keypresses only for a certain period of time. I've spent four hours now googling and still cannot figure out how to do this, even inelegantly.

I read keyboard events using:

```
$(document).keydown(function (event) {  ...... }
```

I think it'd be easier if I was getting people respond by mouse-clicking on buttons (add a listener event?), but :

- I cannot collect responses with mouse clicks and;
- I cannot figure how to add/detach a listener to the document (maybe
  this isn't problem)

Colleagues accomplish this by reloading the page on each iteration/trial of the experiment, but this isn't an option for me.

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Bind/unbind it using namespace. Is that your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery allows you to suffix event names with a namespace (after a period), allowing it to unique identify event handlers for later removal using the exact same name.

You need to use `on` instead:

```
// Use on with a namespaced event
$(document).on('keydown.mytest', function (event) {
   // record keys
});

// After 5 seconds...    
setTimeout(function(){
    // turn off the specific keydown event we registered above
    $(document).off('keydown.mytest');
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! What I was getting wrong was the syntax of what comes after on. There's something I still don't understand though - the event that I'm attaching to the document must be specified in the first command, is that right? At first I tried to change that name entirely and it broke. But I guess you specify the command + a modifier tag to it, so that you can refer to it later?

Comment: @ereii: There are a few version of `on`, but the main two are this one (which just replaces the equivalent function like `keypress()` and the delegated version (which has a jQuery selector as the second parameter and is used for dynamically added elements).

Comment: Thank you so much. It would have been next year before I figured out that logic by myself.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea, given that it did solve my problem. I got quite immediately down-voted, I assume it was because it was quite a stupid/basic question (but I really did literally google for four hours before posting!). Bit disappointing because well there's not really anywhere else I could have gone to get help but at least here you managed to help me out. Sorry if that's why you got dragged down -___-

Answer (score 0):

```
$( yourelement ).on( "keypress", function() {
   //do something
});

setTimeout(function(){ 
    $( yourelement ).off( "keypress" ); 
}, 3000); //time out after 3 seconds
```

Comment: just change the action to keypress. On and off work with keypress. Ill update my code for you,

Comment: Thank you! I went with the next comment cos it gave me a bit more functionality, but I realize that what you've written would do perfectly well!